# Enzyme test a React component that uses readQuery function from react-apollo

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, create-react-app, react-apollo

I have a React component doing this in the `componentDidMount`:

```
apolloClient.readQuery({
  query: authenticatedUserQuery
});
```

This is my Apollo client code:

```
const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
  link: link,
  cache: new InMemoryCache({
    dataIdFromObject: object => object.id
  }),
});
```

I'm trying to test the component with Enzyme but of course I'm getting an error because the `apolloClient` is not mocked.

This is how my test looks like:

```
import React from 'react';
import {shallow} from "enzyme";
import Comment from "./index";

describe('Comment component', () => {
  it('Should render Comment component', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Comment/>);
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

I did not find any information on how to do this.

Comment: What does your test look like?

Comment: @RyanLittle just updated the question with the test.

Comment: What is the error message? You may want to try using Enzyme's [mount](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/mount.md).

Answer (score 0):

I found apollos `MockedProvider`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { MockedProvider } from '@apollo/react-testing';
import {mount} from "enzyme";
import Comment from "./index";

describe('Comment component', () => {
  it('Should render Comment component', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<MockedProvider><Comment/></MockedProvider>);
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

Read this to see how you can mock your query https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/recipes/testing/

Comment: I tried this, `cache` does not have `readQuery` defined in it.